# SQL to answer: which customers were active in a given month, based on activate/deactivate records

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Given a table

```
custid | date       | action
1      | 2011-04-01 | activate
1      | 2011-04-10 | deactivate
1      | 2011-05-02 | activate
2      | 2011-04-01 | activate
3      | 2011-03-01 | activate
3      | 2011-04-01 | deactivate
```

The database is PostgreSQL.

I want an SQL query to show customers that were active at any stage during May.

So, in the above, that would be 1 and 2.

I just can't get my head around the way to approach this. Any pointers?

**update**

Customer 2 was active during May, as he was activated Before May, and not Deactivated since he was Activated. As in, I'm alive this Month, but wasn't born this month, and I've not died.

```
select distinct custid
from MyTable
where action = 'active' and date >= '20110501' and date < '20110601'
```

This approach won't work, as it only shows activations during may, not 'actives'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select t2.custid from
(
-- select the most recent entry for each customer
select custid, date, action 
from cust_table t1 
where date = (select max(date) 
    from cust_table where custid = t1.custid)
) as t2
where t2.date < '2011-06-01'
-- where the most recent entry is in May or is an activate entry
-- assumes they have to have an activate entry before they get a deactivate entry 
and (date > '2011-05-01' or [action] = 'activate')
```

Comment: This is a hybrid solution, but it misses the case where the customer starts May Active, but then is deactivated before the end of the month. Ahh, the subtlety

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @brock - I edited to fix this. I can't test in postgresql but I confirmed it does work in sql server and sqlite

Comment: I used this, and generated some test cases. Seems to work perfectly, and is brief and concise.

Answer (score 3):

Note: This would be a starting point and only works for 2011.

Ignoring any lingering bugs, this code (for each customer) looks at 1) The customer's latest status update before may and 2) Did the customer become active during may?

```
SELECT
  Distinct CustId

FROM
 MyTable -- Start with the Main table

 -- So, was this customer active at the start of may?
 LEFT JOIN  -- Find this customer's latest entry before May of This Year
   (select 
     max(Date) 
   from
     MyTable
   where
     Date < '2011-05-01') as CustMaxDate_PreMay on CustMaxDate_PreMay.CustID = MyTable.CustID

 -- Return a record "1" here if the Customer was Active on this Date
 LEFT JOIN 
   (select
      1 as Bool,
      date
    from
      MyTable
   ) as CustPreMay_Activated on CustPreMay_Activated.Date = CustMaxDate_PreMay.Date and CustPreMay_Activated.CustID = MyTable.CustID and CustPreMay_Activated = 'activated'

 -- Fallback plan: If the user wasn't already active at the start of may, did they turn active during may? If so, return a record here "1"
 LEFT JOIN  
   (select 
     1 as Bool 
   from
     MyTable
   where
     Date <= '2011-05-01' and Date < '2011-06-01' and action = 'activated') as TurnedActiveInMay on TurnedActiveInMay .CustID = MyTable.CustID

 -- The Magic: If CustPreMay_Activated is Null, then they were not active before May
 --            If TurnedActiveInMay is also Null, they did not turn active in May either
 WHERE
   ISNULL(CustPreMay_Activated.Bool, ISNULL(TurnedActiveInMay.Bool, 0)) = 1
```

**Note:**

You might need replace the `FROM MyTable' with

```
From (Select distinct CustID from MyTable) as Customers
```

It is unclear to me just looking at this code whether or not it will A) be too slow or B) somehow cause dupes or problems due starting the FROM clause @ MYTable which may contain many records per customer. The DISTINCT clause probably takes care of this, but figured I'd mention this workaround.

Finally, I'll leave it to you to make this work across different years.

Comment: I briefly considered this kind of approach - I've done similar in code in the past - but thought there might be a simpler approach. I'll code it up in my system and reply back with my findings probably next week. Cheers, Brock

Comment: @Brock - I believe there's a method that allows you to combine the first two tables that I LEFT JOIN into one, but it's beyond my non-research capabilities. Also, I think the three LEFT JOIN's may qualified for two-liner aproaches. Subquery Line 1, ON clause Line 2 -- that could help with the line count a little. However, I usually opt for more lines and better tabbing

Comment: I can change the schema at this stage, however I do have a current status attached to the customer. That doesn't tell me his current status as of 1st of May though.

Comment: @Brock You're absolutely right. I believe the only good alternative in that case is to create a MonthlActive table that is populated by a maintenance task periodically.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL 8.4+:

```
WITH ActivateDates AS (
  SELECT
    custid,
    date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custid ORDER BY date) AS rownum
  FROM atable
  WHERE action = 'activate'
),
DeactivateDates AS (
  SELECT
    custid,
    date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custid ORDER BY date) AS rownum
  FROM atable
  WHERE action = 'deactivate'
),
ActiveRanges AS (
  SELECT
    a.custid,
    a.date AS activated,
    COALESCE(b.date, '21000101'::date) AS deactivated
  FROM ActivateDates a
    LEFT JOIN DeactivateDates d ON a.custid = d.custid AND a.rownum = d.rownum
)
SELECT DISTINCT custid
FROM ActiveRanges
WHERE deactivated > '20110501'
  AND activated   < '20110601'
```